# how do you embed newlines in jquery anchor text?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

sorry i know this has been asked a million times.

i've got the following code:

```
    somediv.append(
        $('<a>', {
            id   : i++,
            text : var1+'\n'+var2+'\n',
            on   : {
                click : function() {
                    alert("you clicked on " + this.id);
                }
            }
        }),
        $('<br />'),
        $('<br />')
    );
```

i want carriage returns to be embedded in the text associated with

does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: You seem to be using line breaks for styling, which is rarely a good idea. Put padding on the anchors instead.

Answer (score 0):

You were close. Change the `text` property to `html`. The `text` property in jQuery usually strips out HTML.

```
var somediv = $('div:first');
var i = 1;
var var1 = 'Var1';
var var2 = 'Var2'
somediv.append(
        $('<a>', {
            id   : 'id_' + i++,
            html : var1+'<br>'+var2+'<br>',
            on   : {
                click : function() {
                    alert("you clicked on " + this.id);
                }
            }
        }),

    );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yz6xL7e1/